# Appending values from one array to another array of unknown dimension

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array A of dimension (654 X 2). Now within a loop, I have an 'if' statement. If for a value of 'i', the condition is true, I need to append the values of 'i'th row of A into a separate array B. That means the dimension of B is not known to me beforehand.  So, how to initialize such array B in python. If this is not the procedure, suggest me alternative ways to execute the same.

Comment: If you do not know where to park a car, how will you park a car? To translate, you need to know the dimensions of B. Maybe B is just 1 dimensional?

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize B as empty array:

```
B = []
```

Then when needs, just append it with the value:

```
B.append( [x,y] )
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try doing something like this:

```
B = []
for i in range(n):
    if i % 2 == 0: # example of condition
        B += [ A[i] ]

print(B)
```

Comment: B.append(A[i]) is a bit faster, but yeah, otherwise I agree.